# Delete/Edit selected record from rendered tabular form results

Tags: 7, forms

I have made a form and retrive form submissions into a tabular format. I put 2 links ahead every single submission - ***Edit/Delete***

Now, when I click "**edit**", its corresponding **edit form** should open. Similarly, when I click "**delete**", that particular entry should get delete from database.

I know it's pretty simple doing in php, but don't know how should i do in Drupal.
Please help.

Some code that I practiced: first I created a menu to show results of my form.

```
$items[MID_MENU_PARENT . '/component/show'] = array(
    'title' => 'Component List',
    'description' => t('Records'),
    'page callback' => 'component_list',
    'access arguments' => array('administer site configuration'),
    'file'=>'component_list.inc',
  );

/**
   * My callback function
**/
  function component_list(){
       $query = db_select('mid_components', 'n')
               ->fields('n')
               ->execute();
       $rows = array();
       while($data = $query->fetchAssoc()){
      // Fill the table rows
       $data['operation'] = l(t('Delete'), 'admin/mid-modules/component' . $data['cid'] . '/delete');
       $data['operation'] .= "|";
       $data['operation'] .= l(t('Edit'), 'admin/mid-modules/component' . $data['cid'] . '/edit');
       $rows[] = array('data' => $data, 'style' => 'word-break:break-all;',);
  }

 // Prepare table header
  $header = array( t('S.No'),t('Component Name'));
  // Output of table with the paging
   $output = theme_table(
     array(
           "header" => $header,
           "rows" => $rows,
           "attributes" => array(),
           "sticky" => true, // Table header will be sticky
           "caption" => "",
           "colgroups" => array(),
           "empty" => t("Table has no row!") // The message to be displayed if table is empty
         )
      );
  return $output;
}

 /**
   * Menu href to edir particular entry
 **/
    $items[MID_MENU_PARENT . '/component/%show/edit'] = array(
          'title' => 'Edit Component item',
          'page callback' => 'component_list_edit',
          'page arguments' => array(3),
          'access arguments' => array('administer users'),
          'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
     );
```

Comment: The question was how to delete or edit a particular table record. I was passing wrong form id now, its resolved. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what your real question is (there is no "question" in your question ...), so consider editing your question to make that clear.

But I would give it a try to add a `/` in front of the 2 (similar) lines containing `admin/mid-modules/component` (so that they are changed to `/admin/mid-modules/component`). So both for the "delete" and the "edit".